# Javascript control for rich text field in lotus notes document

Tags: javascript, controls

I am creating a lotus notes domino application with a simple form with a `richtext` field with that field name of "`body`".
When I set the Web Access option to Using `Java Applet`, the document saves and the text entered in the body is stored in the document.

However, if I change the Web Access display option to Using `Javascript` control, the text entered into the field is not saved.

How do I fix this issue?

I have a javascript function called `saveAndClose` that uses  `_getEditAppletData()`, basically just calls that and then a `form.submit()`

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: function validateDoc()
{
 
  
 if (form.Subject.value == "")
 {
  alert("Please enter the subject of this document.");
  return(false);
 }
 
 if (form.ReaderGroups.options[form.ReaderGroups.selectedIndex].text  == "")
 {
     alert("Please select the Readers.");
     return(false);
 }
 
 return(true);
}
function saveAndClose()
{
  if (validateDoc()) 
  { 
     //  _getEditAppletData();
   form.submit()
  }
}

Comment: please edit your question and add your code.